# implement queue using 2 stacks, with constant time complexity

Tags: data-structures, queue, stack, time-complexity

I'm wondering if it is possible to implement a queue using two stacks so that each queue operation takes amortized constant time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We use 2 stacks with tags "front" and "back".

In front stack we should use size and clear methods, which size returns stack's pointer, and clear sets pointer to 0.

For `enqueue()`, we should push new element to front stack. So the time-complexity will be `O(1)`.

For `dequeue()`, if back stack is empty, we should fill it with elements that are in front stack, for every element that is inside the front stack we should call `pop()` function and then use `push()` function to insert it in back stack, since we know the size of front stack (and it is constant) and pop and push function have time-complexity of `O(1)`, the whole complexity of dequeue will be `O(1)`.

For `size()`, it will return the sum of front and back stacks `size()`.
For `isEmpty()` it should return if the size is equal to zero or not.

Answer (score 1):

```py
class QQ: 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.s = [] 
        self.ss = [] 
    def enque(self, val): 
        self.s.append(val) 
    def deque(self): 
        if not self.s and not self.ss: return None 
        if not self.ss: 
            while self.s: 
                self.ss.append(self.s.pop()) 
        return self.ss.pop()
```

The second stack `ss` holds the content of the first stack `s` in reverse order when we pop the elements of `s` into `ss`. A reversed stack is just a  queue. Whenever `ss` is empty, we load all elements in `s` into `ss`. If it isn't empty we just `deque` one element from it.

The time complexity is amortized constant since we make only one move to `enque`ing and in the long run only 2 moves for `deque`ing.

Comment: thank you, but here the complexity of deque() is not O(1)

Comment: If you change the while loop to 0:self.s.length then, since we know the number of repeats, complexity will be O(1) multiplied by a constant equal O(1). But anyway, I gotta thank you for helping me.

Comment: `deque` has an amortized `O(1)` time complexity. Maybe you are not familiar with python. `while self.s`, where `s` is a list, does what you are describing with `0:self.s.length`. It is true while `self.s` holds any members. When it's empty it breaks.